# Mostrar opções para personalizar orçamento

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso mostrar ao usuário a possibilidade de personalizar um orçamento, mas não estou conseguindo mostrar as opções, funciona somente a primeira, estou usando esse código dentro de um while php.

O que tenho é isso:

O HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Equipamento Analitico E.T.A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="checkbox" name="opcao" value="1" class="personalizar">
  Sim
  <div class="orcamento" style="display: none;">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Sistema Supervisório" type="checkbox" value="Sistema Supervisório" />
          Sistema Supervisorio</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Analisador de PH" type="checkbox" value="Analisador de PH" />
          Analisador de PH </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Monitor de Coagulante" type="checkbox" value="Monitor de Coagulante" />
          Monitor de Coagulante </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Turbidímetro de Entrada" type="checkbox" value="Turbidímetro de Entrada" />
          Turbidímetro de Entrada</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Leitura de Vazao Via IHM" type="checkbox" value="Leitura de Vazao Via IHM" />
          Leitura de Vazao Via IHM </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Analisador de Cloro" type="checkbox" value="Analisador de Cloro" />
          Analisador de Cloro </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Analisador de Fluor" type="checkbox" value="Analisador de Fluor" />
          Analisador de Fluor </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="doseeta" value="1" class="dosadoras">
          Bombas Dosadoras</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
    <div class="dose" style="display: none;">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Cloro" type="checkbox" value="Cloro" />
          Cloro</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Fluor" type="checkbox" value="Fluor" />
          Fluor </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Coagulante" type="checkbox" value="Coagulante" />
          Coagulante </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Acidulante (Acido)" type="checkbox" value="Acidulante (Acido)" />
          Acidulante (Acido)</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Alcalinizante (Soda)" type="checkbox" value="Alcalinizante (Soda)" />
          Alcalinizante (Soda)</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr> 
    </table>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".personalizar").click(function(evento){
        if ($(".personalizar").attr("checked")){
            $(".orcamento").css("display", "block");
        }else{
            $(".orcamento").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dosadoras").click(function(evento){
        if ($(".dosadoras").attr("checked")){
            $(".dose").css("display", "block");
        }else{
            $(".dose").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});`
```

Como posso mostrar as opções?

Comment: Poste o HTML sob o qual o JavaScript está operando.

Comment: Precisa editar e deixar mais claro o que você está tentando fazer, de preferencia poste seu código php tambem

Comment: Como posto um conteúdo HTML? Não estou conseguindo realizar essa operação.

Comment: Para formatar código selecione ele e click no botão `{ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
if (this.checked) {
```

em vez de

```
if ($(".minhaClasse").attr("checked")){
```

Podia também usar o `.prop("checked")`, que é a solução actual/substituta do `.attr()` [desde a versão 1.6](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6).

Mudando isso o seu código já funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/7jGTJ/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".personalizar").click(function (evento) {console.log(1)
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".orcamento").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $(".orcamento").css("display", "none");
        }
    });

    $(".dosadoras").click(function (evento) {
         if (this.checked) {
            $(".dose").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $(".dose").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

**Note** que tinha duas vezes `$(document).ready(){`, eu simplifiquei para uma só.

**Note também** que no seu código não bejo onde esteja a carregar a biblioteca do jQuery. Não se esqueça de incluír este código dentro da tag `<head>`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Nota extra:** pode ainda usar o `$(this).is(':checked')` mas este método é mais útil quando é preciso usar um seletor para encontrar o elemento. Aqui como já temos o `this` então javascript puro é o mais rápido e simples.
<sub>Obrigado @Bruno Augusto lembrar do `.is()`</sub>

Comment: Fantástico Sérgio, muitíssimo obrigado pela grande ajuda, funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Outra possibilidade que fica um pouquinho menos confusa pra quem programa JS "Orientado a Objeto" (aspas bem gigantescas aqui), seria usar *jQuery.is()* condicionando com o pseudo-seletor **:checked**, veja: http://jsfiddle.net/89Dym/

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, verdade. Neste caso não é pratico, mas juntei à resposta também. Obrigado.